# Optional Database Entities

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

**ORIGINAL (see UPDATED QUESTION below)**

I am designing a new laboratory database that tests a wide variety of tests on a wide variety of sample types.

The following list is my current candidate for the list of main entities to best model the laboratory work.

For each entity, a 1-to-many relationship exists from that entity to the entity below.  In other words, every entity (except REQ) has at least columns for *entity*_id and *parent*_id.

Main Entities:
`REQ:` Request (a form)
`SAM:` Sample (the material)
`TST:` Test (requested procedures)
`SUB:` `**` Sub-Test (part of standard test)
`TRI:` `**` Trial (single instance: usually for mean,range, and stddev)
`MEA:` Measurement (a measured number)
`**` Not all tests have subtests, and not all tests have trials.

Sub-tests are a set of tests grouped together by a single name for easy referencing.  For example, a lot acceptance test (LAT) for a particular product is defined as the following tests: viscosity, %-nitrogen, pH, and density.

A trial is a single experiment performed multiple times for product assurance.  For example, fifty bullets might be shot, and each shot is a trial.  The accuracy of each bullet might be required to fall within a certain range, and the average accuracy of all fifty bullets might be required to be in a tighter range.

**Question:**  How should I model cases when sub-tests and/or trials are not needed?

**Option 1:** Use a "blank" sub-test (or trial) if not needed.

**Option 2:** Consider sub-tests and trials to be tests (and have a test_id as a parent), so that measurements always have a test as a parent.

**Option 3:** Optional parents for measurement (trial, sub-test, or test) and trials (sub-test or test).

**Option x:** Any other option worth considering.

**FYI:** If required to answer the question, I will be using Oracle.

---

**UPDATED QUESTION**
In general, my schema is a heirarchy of entities where each entity (except top) must have ONE parent and (except bottom) must have at least one child.  What is the best way to handle cases where an internal entity is unnecessary in certain situation, or what is the benefit/drawback to using a particular option?

**Option 1 (Dummy):** Use a "dummy" entry to indicate entity does not apply in this case.

**Option 2 (Rollup):** Roll-up optional entities into next higher parent entity.

**Option 3 (Pick-a-Parent):** Entity (C) below optional entity (B) with required entity (A) must have ONE parent but the parent can be either the optional entity (B) or the next higher one (A).

**Option x:** Any other option worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your simplified question:

Given a hierarchy as you've described, if I found that some levels in the hierarchy were optional, I would question whether a hierarchy really mapped well to my domain.  I would consider drawing my relations differently, or redefining the entities in my schema.

I don't think a more detailed answer to the general question is possible in a short space like this, since figuring out the best representation of a domain is a) hard, and b) very specific to the particular domain.

Answer (score 1):

Use Outer Joins.  (RIGHT OUTER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN).

They were made specifically for this.

Answer (score 1):

< Edit > This is my first post. Based on the comments, I'll be adding a second post.

Here's my take on an architectural first pass. This stuff generally requires a LOT of back-and-forth with the subject matter experts to get right.

"Test" means one of:
 - Take an action, measure results
 - Take several actions (subtests), measure results for each
 - Make no tests whatsoever (yet you can still have measurements -- ?)

I'd configure this as a "parent" Test table and a child "SubTest" table, where Test can have 0 or more related SubTests, and every SubTest must be related with one and only one Test. (If a test has only one SubTest, enter it in its own table, don't try and track SubTests in the Test table.)

Trials can only exist if there are SubTests. Therefore, Trials are a child of the SubTest table; SubTests can have zero or more Trials, and Trials must be related with one and only one SubTest.

Measures only exist if there are Trials. Therefore, repeat the above, with Measures as a child of Trials.

Can there be SubTests without Trials (or Tests)? If so, then don't enter any Trials.

Can there be Measures without Trials? If no, you don't need any Trials (or SubTests). If yes (?), once again enter some properly labeled dummy/placholder SubTests or Trials as necessary.

Again, this is rudimentary, and more interviews with the folks driving requirements is required.

Comment: All entities (except measurements) must have at least one child.  A test with sub-tests is simply an alias for the group of tests.  A (main) test may have zero or more sub-tests with zero or more trials.  Each measurement and trial (if applicable) must have a parent.

Comment: Well, all entities (except requests) must have a parent too.

Comment: My names distract from my ideas. Is there always a "main" test? How does it differ from SubTests? It sound like "SubTests" are what you'd call those cases were Tests have more than one "main" test. If all tests are created equal, then stick them all in "SubTests"; if some tests are more equal than others, I'd still stick them in "SubTests" and flag them somehow as more important (IsMainTest = TRUE). Then Trials only have to relate to SubTests, and relational integrity is a lot easier to maintain. (continued)

Comment: Nomenclature may be an issue here, with so many things called "tests". I worked in a company years back that did online testing, and we had testers taking tests at test centers with test center monitors and test results and everything was "test" something or other and coherent conversation design all but impossible. Replace them with exams, candidates, proctors, centers, and things started making sense.   /end flashback

Comment: I'll use choosing pizza toppings as an analogy for picking "tests" of for a sample.  A customer could order a pizza with individual toppings (main-test without sub-tests) or pick a specialty pizza (main-test), an alias for a common set of toppings (sub-tests).

Comment: Even though "Meat Lovers" might be pepperoni, sausage, ham, and hamburger, the term "Meat Lovers" would be printed on the receipt and the employee would say here is your "Meat Lovers" pizza. Also, a specialty pizza might have a different price than a custom pizza with the same individual toppings.

Comment: Ah, so SubTests are like a set of actions (pizza toppings) that could be associated with more than one Test (customer ordering pizza)? Over-working the analogy a bit much, if pepperoni was in Meat Lovers, could you also order a pizza with pepperoni (i.e. the same "test" in a Test could also be a SubTest in a set of related tests, and it'd produce the same tests and trials and comparable resulting measures)?

Comment: SubTests are like the set of pizza toppings on a specialty pizza (main test).  You can still order a pepperoni and sausage pizza.  I figured in that case that it would be modeled as two main tests without subtests.

Answer (score 1):

As others have remarked it is hard for us to give a definitive answer without understanding more about your domain.  You have attempted to distill a lot of business rules into a couple of paragraphs but some important information has been lost.  Specifically, it is not possible to be sure whether two entities are genuinely distinct without knowing their attributes.  Having said all which, let's have a go.

A `TEST` is a single procedure.  Despite containing the word "test" a LAT is not a `TEST`  in its own right but is rather a pre-defined set of such procedures.  I would model this scenario as an entity `TEST` with an optional parent entity, which I would prefer to call `TEST_GROUP` (as that is what it is) but it is best to use the domain name, `SUB_TEST`.

A `TRIAL` appears to be distinct from a `TEST`, so model it as a separate entity.  Therefore you have a choice when it comes to `MEASUREMENT`: you can have one entity with two optional foreign keys or you can have `TEST_MEASUREMENT` and `TRIAL_MEASUREMENT`.  Choosing which road to go depends on the characteristics and usage profile.

The following is an initial stab at the entity relationships.  This would be the point in the project when the user goes, "Oh no, that is not what I meant at all."

```
create table sample (
    sample_id number not null
    , constraint samp_pk primary key (sample_id)
)
/
create table sub_test (
    sub_test_id number not null
    , sample_id number not null
    , constraint subt_pk primary key (sub_test_id)
    , constraint subt_samp_fk foreign key (sample_id)
        references sample (sample_id)
)
/
create table test (
    test_id number not null
    , sample_id number not null
    , sub_test_id number 
    , constraint tst_pk primary key (test_id)
    , constraint tst_samp_fk foreign key (sample_id)
        references sample (sample_id)
    , constraint tst_subt_fk foreign key (sub_test_id)
        references sub_test (sub_test_id)
)
/
create table trial (
    trial_id number not null
    , test_id number not null
    , constraint trl_pk primary key (trial_id)
    , constraint trl_tst_fk foreign key (test_id)
        references test (test_id)
)
/
create table measurement (
    measurement_id number not null
    , trial_id number 
    , test_id number 
    , constraint meas_pk primary key (measurement_id)
    , constraint meas_tst_fk foreign key (test_id)
        references test (test_id)
    , constraint meas_trl_fk foreign key (trial_id)
        references trial (trial_id)
    , constraint measurement_ck check (
            (test_id is not null and trial_id is null)
            or (test_id is null and trial_id is not null)
)
/
```

**Edit**

Addressing your more generic question.

> Option 1 (Dummy)

*Never* use a dummy record.  It's is like using a magic value instead of a null.  The solution is worse than the problem it solves.

> Option 2 (Rollup)

This can work when the parent and the child have the same attributes.  But it is not a viable solution if they have different columns, or if they are different dependencies.  Even if they have identical data structures but different business uses it may still be a problem.

> Option 3 (Pick-a-Parent)

This would be my preferred solution.  The snag is the need for a check constraint to ensure that one (and only one) of the eligible foreign keys has been populated.  You also need to guard against allowing too many parents/grandparents/great-grandparents into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand the details of your question, but it sounds like you should have the following:

Table Test
test_id, request, sample, test

Table SubTest
subtest_id, test_id (foreign key to Test)

Table Trial
trial_id, trial_name, measurement, subtest_id

So, Test is a collection of subtests (possibly just one subtest), and a subtest is a collection of Trials (possibly just one trial)

Comment: Each entity can contain multiple children.  Therefore, each entity (except request) has at least self_id, parent_id (of course replacing self and parent with the corresponding names).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain I understand your domain, but could you do something like this?

`Tests` has a `parent_test_id` column, which can be `NULL` (when set, this is a subtest).

`Trials` has a `test_id` column.  (All tests have at least one trial, since you did a thing and had at least one measurement, right?)

`Measurements` has a `trial_id` column.

This does seem to violate your premise, since it stipulates that all tests have at least one trial, so it's possible I misunderstand the requirements.  How can you have a test with no trials?

Anyway, if necessary, you could put both a `trial_id` and a `test_id` on `Measurements`, possibly with a constraint that one or the other must be NULL (and the other must be set).

Comment: The trials entity is primarily used when multiple trials exist.  It doesn't make much sense to perform statistics on a single value.

Comment: Hm.  Well, could you roll the information that would normally be stored in a trial either down in to Measurements or up in to Test, depending on whether they applied to a single run, or the set of all runs?  If a Trial applies to a single run, that seems like an odd place to store the statistical information (as you point out).  If a Test only has a single Measurement, then the statistics fields could just be NULL.

Comment: Please see my simplified question in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a second stab at this one, based on the feedback from my first post. The key thing to understand is that design and architecture can be highly iterative, and I doubt you'll get the ideal model without a lot of back-and-forth--something that doesn't play out to well on Stack Overflow. Odds are you'll take the ideas posted (APC has some good ones), bounce them around with the people you work with, and come up with something that'll work.

My goal these days when designing databases is to try and produce a fully normalized model. Once you've got that, if it doesn't seem reasonable or practical you can denormalize for efficiency, expediency, or whatever -- but the key thing is you denormalize *after* you've found the ideal model. If you stop normalization *before* you get to fully normalized, you haven't denormalized, you've just got a sloppy model.

Here's the entities I see to-date:

What you've labeled as the top-level test, for purposes of clarity here I'm going to call an *Exam*. You define an exam and all its contents (below), and people contact your laboratory to run these exams on their problems.

For any given exam performed for a customer, you run a bunch of **Tests**. Any given test may be used by (required by?) any number of exams.

Often, you get a set of Tests that are done together for more than one Exam. If there are properties that apply to the specific set of Tests, you might want to identify each set as its own entity. Call these **TestGroups**. However, if these are only used associate a specific set of Tests with one or more Exams, you might not get any particular benefit our of defining them as their own entity. (These are your SubTests.)

So, an Exam "has" or "contains" one or more Tests. Alternatively, Exams are related with one or more TestGroups. However, trying to relate an Exam with zero or more TestGroups *and* zero or more individual Tests will produce an overly complex model (let alone physical implmentation), and I'd really want to avoid that. Perhaps a TestGroup can contain a single Test, so Exams only reference TestGroups? Maybe an Exam can only be related to one TestGroup -- in which case that'd be the "many to many" table relating Exams with Tests. This depends on further discussion of requirements with the subject matter experts.

So you have Exams -- Exam definitions, really -- related somehow or other with multiple Tests. Next up, you have a "paid instance" of an Exam (customer X comes in and pays you to test his Widgets). Call this a **CustomerExam**; it has all the contact and billing info, identifies the Exam to be run, and thus is related to the Tests to be performed for the customer. (There's probably a Customer entity out there too...?)

**Trials** are perfomed for the Tests that are part of a CustomerExam. They don't relate with the Exam or the Test, they are an instance of the Trial being performed. (Seems safe to assume that the "meaning/definition" of a Trial would actually be part of a Test--for example, if Test = Is gun accurate, then the work required by a Trial for that Test = fire gun 50 times and measure). So as Trials are performed for the Tests of a given CustomerExam. Are they performed once, or more than once? (Is a trial to fire the gun 50 times, or is each shot counted as a trial? What if they do two rounds of 50 shots?) Whatever, the attributes of the Trial event are stored here -- when it happened, who did it, special notes/circumstances, whatever.

**Measures** are produced by (or for?) Trials. The meaning/definition of each measure is actually part of the definition of a Trial (which is part of the definition of a Test); the event of the Trial produces specific values for the defined/anticipated Measures. The assumption is that a Trial will generate zero (?) or more Measures, so Measures are their own entity.

Looking back at this, it seems like there's some form of implicit double stucture: a set of tables to define available Exams, Tests, Trials, and Measures (what can be examined, how can it be tested, what shall we measure) and a companion set of tables to track specific instances of each (who wanted it, who did the work, when did they do it, what were the results)

I've got to have way over-anazled this problem. The key thing here is, as with all design sessions, in posing ideas and asking questions, did they generate your own ideas, questions, or answers?