# Optional Database Entities (part 2)

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

**See 'Almost Decided' below**

---

NOTE: This is a continuation and simplification of [Optional Database Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359095/optional-database-entities).

I am designing a new laboratory database that tests a wide variety of tests on a wide variety of sample types.

Main Entities: 
  Each must have **exactly one** parent (except `REQ`) and **at least one** child (except `MEA`).

```
 Request      REQ - the form
 Sample       SAM - the materials on the form to be tested
 Test         TST - the procedures to be performed on the sample
(Trial **     TRI - instance of duplicate methods for statistics)
 Measurement  MEA - a single measured number
 ** A Trial is optional. (see below)
```

**Optional Trial Explanation**
Many tests are a simple procedure with a few measurements.  For example, "Add 10 mL 15% of KNO3 to sample then obtain density and pH."

However, some tests call for the same procedure to be performed on distinct portions of a sample.  Lets use ballistics testing as an example.  The requester might ask for the average exit velocity and accuracy for these 20 bullets.  The `sample` is the set of 20 bullets.  The `test` is "collect exit velocity and accuracy."  The `trials` are the 20 individual shots being fired.  The `measurements` are exit velocity and accuracy for each shot (`trial`).

**QUESTION** 
How should I model the entities `Test`, `Trial`, and `Measurement`, since the `Trial` entity is optional?

**Option 1:** Use a "blank" trial entity as a placeholder if not needed.
Good: Parent entity always the same.
Bad: `Trial` entries exist even when not needed.

**Option 2:** Roll `Trial` into the `Test` table as a sub-test.  A measurement would then always have a `test` as a parent.
Good: Single parent type for measurement (`Test`)
Bad: Multiple parent type for `Test`: `Sample` or `Test`

**Option 3:** A measurement still has one parent, but the parent could be either a `test` or a `trial`.
Good: Single parent type for `Test` (and `Event` when required)
Bad: Multiple parent type for `Measurement`: `Test` or `Trial`

**Option 4:** Trial as sub-entity.  `Measurement` has required `test_id` and optional `trial_num`.  Trial has a PK of (`test_id`, `trial_num`).
Good: No multiple parent type.
Bad: Not sure

**Option X:** Any other option not already mentioned.

---

---

**Almost Decided:** I now believe Option 4  (Trial as sub-entity) is the best.  The following are the basic rules for Option 4.
 - A `measurement` always belongs to a `test`.
 - A `trial` only exists when needed.
 - `Trial_num` is set when multiple trials exist under a set.
 - Otherwise `trial_num` is null to indicate a `trial` is not needed.

```
Simple ER Diagram
-----------------
REQ <- SAM <- TST <- MEA
              ^        |  
              |        |  
              |-(TRI)<-|    

Table Keys
----------

 Table | PK              | FK
 ------+-----------------+----------------
 REQ   | REQ_id          |  
 SAM   | SAM_id          | REQ.PK
 TST   | TST_id          | SAM.PK
(TRI   | TST_id, TRI_num | TST.PK )
 MEA   | MEA_id          | TST.PK, TRI.PK*

* TRI.PK is null if trial entity is not needed.
```

Please offer any thoughts on why it is a good or bad option.

Comment: Could you explain the `Trial` a little more? How is a `Trial` different from a `Test` with multiple `Measurements`?

Comment: Have you considered using a non-relational database like couchdb?

Comment: Jeff, see edited "Trial Explanation".

Comment: David, we are already familiar with Oracle and already have the resources in place for the new database. We expect the number of measurements to be in the ballpark of tens of millions per year, and I like the advanced features of Oracle to handle this (materialized views, partitioning, etc). Far more people know Oracle than CouchDB. Finally, I don't know if I have the time to learn a new DBMS and complete this project on time.  However, if you still believe that I should seriously consider couchdb or another non-relational db, please answer with a detailed reason why.

Comment: I can't help feeling SO is not the ideal environment for this question. What it really needs is a two hours face-to-face around a whiteboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear why it's necessary to represent a `Trial` as a distinct entity. Why isn't the following schema adequate?

```
Sample        Test           Measurement
------        ----           -----------
SampleId (PK) TestId (PK)    MeasurementId (PK)
Description   SampleId (FK)  TestId (FK)
              TestStartDate  Description
              TestEndDate    MeasuredValue
```

From what you've said so far, it sounds like you could just *infer* that a `Test` with more than one `Measurement` counts as a `Trial`. That is, if your user interface needs to show that a particular Test had a Trial, if could just do the following:

```
if (test.Measurements.Count > 1) {
    _View.Title = test.TestName + " (Trial)"; 
}
```

If that's not true, what attributes do you need that this schema is missing? What else needs to be in the `Trial` table that isn't available here?

---

**Update**: given the additional details, I would recommend introducing a new entity, which I'll call `TestRun`. A `TestRun` just groups one or more `Measurements` within a `Test`.  `Trials` are now associated with `TestRuns`.

The resulting schema looks like this:

```
Sample        Test           TestRun         Measurement
------        ----           -------         -----------
SampleId (PK) TestId (PK)    TestRunId (PK)  MeasurementId (PK)
Description   SampleId (FK)  TestId (FK)     TestRunId (FK)
              TestStartDate                  Description
              TestEndDate                    MeasuredValue

Trial
-----
TrialId (PK)
TestRunId (FK)
Description
```

This is very close to **Option 1** in the original question. If the cost of maintaining a blank (or dummy) `Trial` are low - for example, if `Trials` have few or no attributes - that may be a better solution.

Comment: In those tests where a set of measurements is taken multiple times, a trial is a single set of those measurements. Examples: record temperature and pressure every 5 minutes for an hour, record velocity and accuracy of 30 bullets when shot, etc. In contrast, simple tests (as described in the original question) have multiple measurements but do not require multiple trials.

Comment: In a way, a `trial` is a member of an array of a particular set of measurements.  In many cases, a `specification` must compare against the average (or other function) of a particular `measurement` rather than the individual `measurements`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from your explanation, this can be said:

> A Test may have one or many Trials
>   assocaited to it and a Trial may only
>   be associated with one Test.

In which case, a Trial is a child entity of a Test. If that is true, then you might have two tables:

Test
Trial

The Trial table would have a foreign key field back to the Test table (which signifies the relationship). That way, each Trial would be associated with exactly one Test and each Test could have multiple related Trials.

Comment: Can a Measurement belong to more than one Test or Trial?

Comment: No. Every entity (except request) has exactly one parent and (except measurement) has at least one child.

Comment: Then it's possible to use a trick used by Microsoft in Microsoft Project. Your Measurement table would have two fields to identify the relationship. One would be parentId, and then a parentTypeId. parentId would be the ID of the parent element and parentTypeId would be an identifier to signify whether the parent is a Test or Trial (or any other type you need).

Comment: First, I would implement "exactly one parent in `Test` or `Trial`" in `Measurement` by having two FK,nullable columns `test_id` and `trial_id` with a check constraint on `test_id NOT NULL XOR trial_id NOT NULL`.

Comment: Second, you believe my "Option 3" (not 4) is best?

Comment: Partially. I wouldn't implement it the way you are talking though. Your method results in one field or the other having a null value. What I suggest leaves no nulls. parentId would be the id value of any kind of parent, and the parentIdType would be a flag telling you which entity the id belonged to.

Comment: @Steven - if every `Test` must have at least one `Trial`, why wouldn't you just make `Measurement` a child of `Trial`?

Comment: Not all `Tests` need a `Trial`.  An example is in my main question, "Optional Trial Explanation", first paragraph.  I could force every `Test` to have a `Trial`, which is my Option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kite, borne aloft by assumption and interpretation.

A `request` comes with a `sample` and a specification of procedures to be carried out on the sample.  If the `sample` is singular (a bottle of liquid) then this is a *test* and one set of measurements is collected.  If the `sample` is multiple (a box of bullets, a time series) then this is a *trial* and a repeated set of measures is collected, one per `sample` instance.

In other words, the test/trial dichotomy is a red herring, and `measurement` is an intersection table between `test` and `sample`.

```
REQUEST
-------
RequestId (PK)
Specification

SAMPLE
------
RequestId (FK)
SampleId (PK)

TEST
----
RequestId (FK)
TestId (PK)
TestStartDate
TestEndDate

MEASUREMENT
-----------
TestId (FK)   
SampleId (FK) 
MeasurementDescription
MeasuredValue
```

`Measurement(TestId,SampleId)` is a compound unique key.  Depending on how you feel about composites you may wish to define a surrogate `MeasurementId (PK)` as well.

Obviously there may be some further normalisation may be required.  For example, you may want/need to split sample into two tables `sample` and `sample_instance`.  It's hard to tell without knowing all the attribues involved.